# I am trying to code Canny edge detection in C#

Tags: c#, sobel

I am trying to code Canny edge detection in C#. I am confused about finding the Direction of the edge. I know The Direction is the angle between the gradient vector and the x-axis. When finding the gradient vector's Direction (D), you do inverse tan of the y/x ratio.
I understand that part. The part that I am lost at is some examples online seem to add PI out of nowhere, and I do not understand. So is it :

```
                ` double angle = X/ Y;
                double radians = angle * (180/Math.PI); 
                Angle = Math.Tan(radians) + Math.PI;`
```

or this:

```
                double angle = X/ Y;
                double radians = angle * (180/Math.PI); 
                Angle = Math.Tan(radians);
```

I have also seen :

```
               orientation[index] = Math.Atan2(dy, dx) + Math.PI;
```

but this is not even inverse tan or is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Both your first examples don't make any sense. X / Y is surely not an angle but the tangens of an angle.
To get the angle from the tangens you must use the one of the two inverse functions Math.Atan or Math.Atan2.
Always prefer Math.Atan2 over Math.Atan if you have got both components (X and Y) of the direction vector because Math.Atan2 returns an unambiguous angle in the range for -Pi to +Pi, while Math.Tan only gives you a result in the range form -Pi/2 to +Pi/2. Then you have to decide if in a certain case you have to add or subtract Pi (ATan doesn't "know" whether the angle is in the first or in the third quadrant if the result is positive or whether it is in the second or fourth quadrant if the result is negative).
Try to learn how to work with trigonometric functions and when you understand how to apply them and the corresponding inverse trigonometric functions come back to your programme.
And read the Microsoft documentation concerning the trigonometric functions.